# Pass values of ng-repeat outside it as parameters on button click

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code structure where inside a modal-popup, I've populated rows of a table using `ng-repeat`. Now I want to pass the values of 3 columns of all the rows to the `controller` but I dont know how exactly I would be able to use the data outside `ng-repeat` scope and pass to the `controller`. Here's my code snippet -

```
    <div class="inmodal">
        <div class="modal-header" ng-model="modalDetails">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
            <img ng-src={{$root.varImg}} class="m-b-md" alt="profile">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{$root.assetGrpNm}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">       
                                <div ng-repeat="dataag in detail.outerData" >
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                        <!-- --------- I tried using this piece of code thinking that atleast the values would be inside ng-repeat scope 
                                            <tr><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="save(deviceId,dataDeviceData.measurementData,newDeviceValue,dataDeviceData.lastReadingDateTime)">Save</button></tr> 
                                          -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Id</th>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Last Value</th>
                                                <th>Current Value</th>
                                                <th>Date Time</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="dataDevice in dataag.innerData track by $index">
                                                <td>
                                                <span style="font-weight: 800;"><span ng-model="deviceId">{{dataDevice.managedDeviceInfo.id}}</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{dataDevice.managedDeviceInfo.deviceExternalId}}</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td ng-repeat="dataDeviceData in dataDevice.deviceCoreData">{{dataDevice.managedDeviceInfo.deviceName }}&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span class="text-center">({{ dataDeviceData.quantityUnitSymbol }})</span></td>
                                                <td ng-repeat="dataDeviceData in dataDevice.deviceCoreData">
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="modal_val" ng-model="dataDeviceData.measurementData" required style="width: 100px;"></td>
                                                <td ng-repeat="dataDeviceData in dataDevice.deviceCoreData">
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="modal_val" ng-model="newDeviceValue" required style="width: 100px;"></td>
                                                <td style="position: relative;">
                                                 <div id="datetimepicker1-{{$index}}" class="input-append date">
                                                    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" ng-model="dataDeviceData.lastReadingDateTime"></input>
                                                    <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="save(deviceId,dataDeviceData.measurementData,newDeviceValue,dataDeviceData.lastReadingDateTime)">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="ok()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is an image showing the logic - 
[image: Ng-repeat Logic]

Comment: there is no need to be inside `ng-repeat` scope, since your data is already in `$cope.dataag.innerData`. you can filter your column inside button click function.

Comment: @anoop okay, but I want to pass the values of ng-repeat (here the black blocks) to the controller on clicking the button. What shall I do then?